# ant : error in console and no with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, compiler-errors, javac

I work with Eclipse and my project is running well.
I make a ant file, build.xml, and if I run it with Eclipse it's all right.
Now I would like execute it in console, I put in the correct folder and I type ant.
This time I have a problem with javac.
Why I have a problem in console and no with Eclipse ? 
I just want to compile my code !

---

Error is :

```
    [javac] /home/clacroix/workSpace/src/controleur/TraiterFeuilleDeCalcul_nTableaux.java:202: illegal start of expression
[javac]     private static Extremite rechercheExtremitesTableaux(Coordonnees caseNonVide) 
[javac]     ^
[javac] /home/clacroix/workSpace/src/controleur/TraiterFeuilleDeCalcul_nTableaux.java:202: illegal start of expression
[javac]     private static Extremite rechercheExtremitesTableaux(Coordonnees caseNonVide) 
[javac]             ^
[javac] /home/clacroix/workSpace/src/controleur/TraiterFeuilleDeCalcul_nTableaux.java:202: ';' expected
[javac]     private static Extremite rechercheExtremitesTableaux(Coordonnees caseNonVide) 
[javac]                             ^
[javac] /home/clacroix/workSpace/src/controleur/TraiterFeuilleDeCalcul_nTableaux.java:202: ')' expected
[javac]     private static Extremite rechercheExtremitesTableaux(Coordonnees caseNonVide) 
[javac]                                                                     ^
[javac] /home/clacroix/workSpace/src/controleur/TraiterFeuilleDeCalcul_nTableaux.java:202: illegal start of expression
[javac]     private static Extremite rechercheExtremitesTableaux(Coordonnees caseNonVide) 
[javac]                                                                                 ^
[javac] /home/clacroix/workSpace/src/controleur/TraiterFeuilleDeCalcul_nTableaux.java:202: ';' expected
[javac]     private static Extremite rechercheExtremitesTableaux(Coordonnees caseNonVide) 
[javac]
```

---

My build.xml is :

```
<project default="run">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="bin.dir"     value="bin"/>
<property name="bib.dir"     value="bibliotheque"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="exe"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="tableXL.Main"/>
<property name="jar-name"    value="S2RDB.jar"/>

<property name="library" value=". bibliotheque.jdom-2.0.5.jar; bibliotheque.jxl.jar"/>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${bib.dir}">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
             <pathelement location="${bin.dir}"/>
           </classpath>
        </javac>
        <echo message="compilation finie"/>
    </target>


    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${jar-name}" basedir="${bin.dir}">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${bib.dir}" includes="*.jar" excludes=""/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${library}" />
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <echo message="Creation du fichier Jar finie"/>
    </target>


    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${jar-name}" fork="true"/>
    </target>
```

---

My function is :

```
import tableXL.Coordonnees;
import tableXL.Extremite;
import java.util.ArrayList;

private static Extremite rechercheExtremitesTableaux(Coordonnees caseNonVide) 
{
ArrayList<Coordonnees> casesPleines = new ArrayList<Coordonnees>();
casesPleines.add(caseNonVide);
while(true)
{
    ArrayList<Coordonnees> nouvellesCases = rechercheCasesAutour(casesPleines);
    if(nouvellesCases != null && nouvellesCases.size() != 0)
    {
        for(Coordonnees coord : nouvellesCases)
        {
            casesPleines.add(coord);    
        }   

        vue.actualiserTraite(nouvellesCases.size());
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
return new Extremite(casesPleines);
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: That's your entire Java file?

Comment: Please post the complete `TraiterFeuilleDeCalcul_nTableaux.java` file

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I resolved the problem. I installed the last version of javac and now it's all right. I think that some things are okay for the new version (7) and no for the precedent version (6).